# issues about Spring initialization in different environment

Tags: spring, initialization

I have some questions about spring's initialization in different environment.

**1. In web container context, such as tomcat.**

I knew that spring can be  initialized by declaring

`org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` in `<listener-class>` field.

It will be initialized automatically when tomcat is started. (I think this is right :-）  )

**2. In JUnit context**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:appContext.xml")
```

annotations can be used to initialize the Spring context.

Under these two cases, we can use such as

```
@Autowired 
private ServiceDao serviceDao;
```

to use the serviceDao, and  **we almost never used the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method.**

**3. In a common J2SE environment**

Should I must initialize the spring context manually,

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(xx.xml)
```

and then use `appContext.getBean(XX)` to get the bean?

in this case, can `@Autowired` be used?

How to do this?

**Updated:**
I try the spring-boot, I think the variable can be autowired, because the class is annotated with `@Component`， and with the `@ComponentScan` in main class, the variable can be autowired.

But I used spring xml before, and I have some injection like this, I don't know how to autowire the variable.

```
<bean id="XXXMap" class="com.xx">
     <property name="handlerMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="XXX" value="YYY"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

use the `@component`, I believe `XXXMap` can be autowired, but how the map is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use @Autowired no matter how you create the application context.

There are several ways to create an application context in a standalone application. You can of course still use the traditional XML configuration files but an alternative option worth considering is [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). It allows you to create completely annotation driven applications that mostly rely on conventions over configuration. Bootstrapping a simple standalone application reduces to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(userService.findUser(42L));
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I try the spring-boot, It's Good! <p></p> But I used it with a

Comment: I try the spring-boot, It's Good! But I used it with the application-context xml, because I config the sessionFactory,datasource ... in the xml. I don't have an example to work without the xml.

Comment: I have updated the question, because the comment style is too limited to express my idea. Thank you!